# Programatically send images to v4l2-device

Tags: python, webcam, gstreamer, v4l2

I have a program that generates jpgs. I would like to send these images to my virtual webcam when they are generated. I can create a virtual webcam using `v4l2loopback` and have been looking at gstreamer, but can't quite get it to work.

I've tried gst-launch with multifilesrc, but that seems to only work when I have images already generated. I've also tried setting gst-launch to just send one image to the webcam and then just overwrite the image when a new one is generated. This, unfortunately, causes gstreamer to crash.

Does anyone know how I might be able to do this? I don't have to use gstreamer, but I am looking to do implement this in Linux, ideally in Python.

Comment: Why are you trying to send images _to_ the camera? What do you want the camera to do with them? A microphone can be used as a poor quality speaker, but I don't think a camera can be used as a hologram projector.

Comment: I want to send it to a virtual webcam so that I can then stream these images in a VoIP chat.

Comment: So your question _really_ is, how do you stream custom images to your VoIP client that is expecting a video stream and really has nothing to do with webcams.

Comment: Yeah. I guess I am asking this question with the assumption that sending images through the camera feed is the best way to do it. Are you aware of a better way?

Comment: implementing it in gstreamer does not contradict "implementing in linux". as a matter of fact, v4l2loopback is only available on linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following script will monitor a directory and pass every newly added image to gstreamer which will send it to the video-device (`/dev/video0`, but change at will).

call with the path to monitor as the sole argument (e.g. `./pics2v4l2 /tmp/pics`)

```
#!/bin/sh

DIR=$1
DEVICE=/dev/video0

inotifywait -m "${DIR}" \
| awk '$2== "CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE" {print $1"/"$3; fflush()}' \
| while read f; do
 gst-launch-0.10 uridecodebin uri="file://${f}" \
 ! ffmpegcolorspace \
 ! videoscale \
 ! imagefreeze \
 ! identity error-after=2 \
 ! v4l2sink show-preroll-frame=false device=${DEVICE}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Script for gst-launch-1.0

```
DIR=$1
DEVICE=/dev/video0

inotifywait -m "${DIR}" \
| awk '$2== "CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE" {print $1"/"$3; fflush()}' \
| while read f; do
 gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri="file://${f}" \
 ! videoconvert \
 ! videoscale \
 ! imagefreeze \
 ! identity error-after=2 \
 ! v4l2sink show-preroll-frame=false device=${DEVICE}
done
```

Execute using

```
sh <FILE_NAME>.sh <DIRECTORY_PATH>
```